# the code isn't working.it run infinitely?

Tags: java, mysql

```java
String dumpCommand = "C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.0\\bin\\mysqldump" + " -u " + user + " -p" + " " + database + " > " + path;         
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
File test = new File(path);
PrintStream ps;
try{
    Process child = rt.exec(dumpCommand);
    System.out.println("Child" + child);
    ps = new PrintStream(test);
    InputStream in = child.getInputStream();
    int ch;

    while ((ch = in.read()) != -1) {
        ps.write(ch);
        System.out.write(ch);
    }         
}
```

The code isn't working. It run infinitely? How can I run mysqldump on java?

Comment: Don't use `Runtime.exec()`, use a `ProcessBuilder`

Comment: How to use ProcessBuilder() for mysqldump command.Project location in D: drive. Mysqldump location is  C:\ProgramFiles\MySQL\MySQLServer5.0\bin\mysqldump\

Comment: Is this Java 7 or Java 6? Answer depends on that

Comment: k using java 6 ....please help me fast

Answer (score 2):

Since the path to the command you want to run contains spaces, you need quotes around it:

```
String dumpCommand = "\"C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.0\\bin\\mysqldump\""+ " -u " + user +" -p" + " "+ database +" > "+path;
```

**EDIT**

A [`ProcessBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) will make this job easier:

```
// Step 1: set up the command line
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(
    "C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.0\\bin\\mysqldump",
    "-u",
    user,
    "-p"
    database);

// Step 2: redirect output
File test = new File(path);
pb.redirectOutput(test);

// Step 3: start the process
Process proc = pb.start();
```

The `ProcessBuilder` class has many other features (consult the documentation), including the ability to define the environment variables for the subprocess, setting the current directory, and redirect error output. The latter might be extremely useful in diagnosing problems if things go wrong.

Comment: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program ""C:\ProgramFiles\MySQL\MySQLServer5.0\bin\mysqldump"": CreateProcess error=3, The system cannot find the path specified
 at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:460)
 at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:593)
 at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:431)
 at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:328)
 at Dbcon.demoback.main(demoback.java:65)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=3, The system cannot find the path specified

Comment: How to use ProcessBuilder() for mysqldump command.Project location in D: drive. Mysqldump location is  C:\ProgramFiles\MySQL\MySQLServer5.0\bin\mysqldump\

Comment: @Ajithlal - I added some sample code. It might be worthwhile to try executing the command you are building directly from the command line to verify that it works, and only then trying to execute it from Java.

Comment: But i am using java 6 pb.redirectOutput not working

Comment: @Ajithlal - With Java 6, you'll have to redirect to the file yourself. You can read the program output by calling `proc.getInputStream()` after you've started the process and write what you read to a `FileOutputStream` directed to `path`. You can also read the error output separately by calling `proc.getErrorStream()`, or, if it's more convenient, you can merge error output into the standard program output by calling `pb.redirectErrorStream(true)` before starting the process.

Answer (score 0):

or you can use String.trim() method to filter the space out.

Comment: trim just cuts the whitespace at start and end of the string.
What Ted is writing is adressed at the blanks in the filepath of the executable where trim would break the command if it would filter the spaces.